# How can I schedule OneSignal notifications programmatically from a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I am developing a Flutter app where I want to schedule OneSignal notifications from the app itself based on some conditions related to the user, I was not able to find something useful in the [OneSignal Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter).

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827952/sending-onesignal-notification-from-flutter) on stackoverflow that shows people are actually able to schedule notifications using OneSignal Flutter package, but, the `shared` property used in that example is not exposed anymore, and I couldn't find something useful in the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) of the OneSignal Flutter SDK.

Does anyone know if this is functionality was removed from the OneSignal Flutter package or only changed to something else?

I have installed the OneSignal package on my app, and it is perfectly working when I send a notification from OneSignal website, but, my goal is to schedule that notification from the app itself through OneSignal package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the OneSignal support, they have answered clearly that they removed this scheduling notifications functionality from OneSignal Flutter SDK starting from version 5, quoting from their support email:

> With that said, with the migration to version 5, we have removed the ability to send push from the SDK itself. To do this now, you would instead add the notification create request in as an HTTP request.